# Show if complex function $f(z)$ contains all real coefficients then $f(\bar z)$ = $\bar {f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Note: Suppose $f(z)$ is a polynomial or a proper/strictly proper rational function.

Can someone demonstrate why if all coefficient of $f(z)$ are real then relation $f(\bar z)$ = $\bar {f(z)}$ hold

Is there a theorem for this result?

Comment: Which coefficients?

Comment: Whack a complex conjugate on everything and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply follows from the fact that the complex conjugate preserves addition and multiplication - that is:
$$\overline{a+b}=\overline a + \overline b$$
$$\overline{ab}=\overline a \cdot \overline b.$$
It then follows that
$$\overline{x^n}=\overline{x}^n$$
meaning that a polynomial has:
$$\overline{P(x)}=\overline{a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1x + a_0}=\overline{a_n}\cdot\overline{x}^n+\overline{a_{n-1}}\cdot\overline{x}^{n-1}+\ldots + \overline{a_1}\cdot\overline{x}+\overline{a_0} $$
However, if all the $a_i$ are real, it follows that they are conjugate to themselves hence $a_i=\bar{a_i}$ and we have that $P(\bar x)$ would then be equal to the above, $\overline{P(x)}$.

Then, since you can easily get $$\overline{\frac{a}b}=\frac{\overline a}{\overline b}.$$
out of the fact that multiplication is preserved by conjugation, you can apply the same argument to the quotient of polynomials.

Comment: Easy points, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Nice answer. You can use this to easily show that, in fact, the statements are equivalent: $P(\overline{z}) = \overline{P(z)}$ for all $z$ if and only if all of the coefficients of $P$ are real.